# Combining Conditions in XPath and XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to build an XPath select just the 'Phone' number from the following:

```
<element identifier="ContactPoint" version="Local">
    <qualifier name="Phone" type="refining"/>
    01234 567890
</element>
<element identifier="ContactPoint" version="Local">
    <qualifier name="Email" type="refining"/>
    jbloggs@jbloggs.com
</element>
```

In my XSLT, I have the following:

```
<TelNumber>
    <xsl:value-of select="./element[@identifier='ContactPoint']"/>
</TelNumber>
```

But obviously this will just select the first instance. How would I combine conditions into one select to ensure I am only selecting the value of "element" with a "Phone" qualifier child?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.\element[@identifier='ContactPoint' and qualifier/@name='Phone']`